# Using Google BlobStore with an Android application

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, http, blobstore

I found 1 thread about this question, which did partially answer the question, but I'm afraid I may need some details.

I'm currently trying to use BlobStore with my android app, and I can't get anything else than a 501 error (the HTTP server can not handle your request).

He is my code ;

```
HttpPost httpPostImg = new HttpPost(url);
Header header = new BasicHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
Header h = new BasicHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");             
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
FormBodyPart form = new FormBodyPart("myFile",new ByteArrayBody(image,"multipart/form- data","pict.jpeg"));
entity.addPart(form);
httpPostImg.setEntity(entity);
httpPostImg.setHeader(header);
httpPostImg.setHeader(h);
response = httpClient.execute(httpPostImg);
processResponse(response);
```

I get the URL by a GET request which is working quite well. I also try a FormBodyPart containing a ByteArrayBody, and also to set mime type for the ByteArrayBody to "multipart/form-data" but nothing worked. I always get a 501 error (server can not handle your request).

Thanx, all answers are appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried comparing the data your Android app is uploading to a regular browser form post, to see where the differences lie?

Comment: I did, using wireshark. The data seems almost the same, except a problem about boundary.  
"the multi part dissector could not find the boundary parameter"
What am I missing ? :/

Comment: Ok, it was really tricky. Seems that headers are not at all required, and that they mess everything up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after some search, here is the solution ;

It seems that headers are not working as I expected, so I just deleted them.

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
entity.addPart("data", new ByteArrayBody(image,"image/jpeg","avatar.jpg"));
httppost.setEntity(entity);
response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
processResponse(response);
```

Comment: That's it. The overall entity is multi-part mime, and you set the mime type of each part (optionally) in it's constructor, then it get's added to the multi-part.

Comment: I tried this like you but it doesn't store my image in the blobstore. Is the variable image an byte[]??

Answer (score 1):

I used the following and it worked.

This is an example if you post as gzip content:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream gzos = null;
    try {
        gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
        gzos.write(xml.getBytes());
    } finally {
        if (gzos != null)
            try {
                gzos.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
    }

    byte[] fooGzippedBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    entity.addPart("name", new ByteArrayBody(fooGzippedBytes,"application/x-gzip", "filename"));

    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
```