# How would I use blobstore to process android images

Tags: android, google-app-engine, blobstore, google-cloud-endpoints

Can someone please clarify this for me. I am reading the developer page about the blobstore at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview. I can't seem to wrap my head around the process of saving and retrieving blobs? It sounds like

- android app would directly send an image to the blobstore
- after saving the image, the blobstore would then return a blobkey to my backend for me to put in the datastore

Is that the process? Maybe it's because I have had a long day, but I just can't see it. If someone has an example they don't mind sharing, please post it. I just need to save images from android in the blobstore and then be able to retrieve them with blobkey or otherwise.

I have already look at

- [Upload to Appengine Blobstore in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436593/upload-to-appengine-blobstore-in-android)
- [Using Google BlobStore with an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177243/using-google-blobstore-with-an-android-application)
- [Android Interaction with Google App Engine Blobstore Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423890/android-interaction-with-google-app-engine-blobstore-service)
- [What is the syntax to get a Blobstore upload url from Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165993/what-is-the-syntax-to-get-a-blobstore-upload-url-from-android)

For the life of me, I don't know why they are not doing it for me.

I suppose some questions are:

- How does android know where to send the blob to? I mean, does Google distinguish between my instances of the blobstore versus other people's instances, similar to how it distinguishes my instances of the datastore? In other words could I go to app engine `Applications Overview` and see all the blobs that belong to my app the way I could in the datastore? I suppose a complete, working piece of code could help me see these answers.

Part of my problem could be that I have never used servlet. I am presently using Google Cloud Endpoint for my api.

Comment: been wondering if you have any working code on this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description of the process is correct.  The only step you miss is the first: the server side calls  blobstoreService.createUploadUrl(redirecturl) to generate the URL to upload to.  Then the handler at redirecturl will save the blob key to the datastore.

Comment: Is that url set forever or is it dynamic? As in does the android app need to call for it each time it needs to save a blob or an I get it once and then store it on the client and use it each time I need to send a blob?

Comment: it's dynamic.  That function creates a new url for each blob.  I'm not sure if Endpoints has a specific way to deal with it, but the general case with Blobstore is that you need to use createUploadUrl() each time you want to upload something to Blobstore.

Comment: @dragonx when blobstore calls server thru callback url, how does the server know which user that callback is for?

Answer (score 3):

Actually there are two ways to upload to blobstore:

Using [direct upload handler](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Uploading_a_Blob):

- Server gets a unique one-time secret upload url via `createUploadUrl(..)` and sends this url to client.
- Client uses `multipart/form-data` POST to upload data to this url.
- The upside is that you can upload large files (>32mb).

Using [blobstore `FileService` API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstorehttp://) which is **deprecated** and **should not be used any more**:

- You create you own POST upload handler where client uploads data.
- You use `FileService` API so save data to blobstore.
- The downside is that you can upload max 32mb of data (generic GAE request limit).
- The upside is that you have access to data so you can edit contents if needed.