# how to download file from google blobstore to android

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, blob, blobstore

I can't find any example shows how to download blob file from google blob store using blob key.
I can upload file to blob store and get blob key I wonder how to use this blob key to download this file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check here if this is what you are talking about I would also suggest contacting support:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/

Also check this question out it discusses, the Blob store more: [Google App Engine Use Blobkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704816/google-app-engine-use-blobkey)
private BlobInfoFactory infoFactory = new BlobInfoFactory();

I also retrieved this from here check it out :[Using Google BlobStore with an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177243/using-google-blobstore-with-an-android-application?rq=1)

BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(req.getParameter("blob-key"));
BlobInfo info = infoFactory.loadBlobInfo(blobKey);